# How can I merge downloaded YouTube videos into one?

Tags: windows, video, youtube

I have downloaded 18 videos of a movie from YouTube in `.flv` format.

Which software can I use to merge all 18 videos into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/).

First I'd convert them into raw video, merge them, encode them into x264+ogg(mp4). But you should grab those movie files in better quality which already comes in mp4. Tell us where did you get it (if its a video sharing site like YouTube), there is a way I guess to get a better copy.

Comment: I have said, i downloaded all from youtube in flv format.

Comment: Oh sorry. Try using http://deturl.com/ or 'youtube-dl' or something which grabs the best format (which should be in mp4).

Comment: I just got sent to this thread when I tried to ask a question on this--the supplied answer does *NOT* work for me. I get a warning about H.264 B-frames. I'm left with a choice between bad stuttering or video that plays far faster than it should.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - I just accept those messages and I found no problem with the video speeds at all. You may want to play with the filters, especially the ones about speed. Maybe you try to join a specific, weird video file.

Comment: @Shiki: I tried turning off the custom framerate that had been selected (which was just a hair off the default) and tried it again.  This time I paid a bit more attention to exactly what was wrong--the VIDEO is fine, the audio is running too fast and within seconds it's obvious it no longer matches up with the video.

Comment: @Shiki:  Followup:  It's a problem with AviDemux.  The 2.6 experimental version merged them fine.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - Check the changelog. It may be a new feature.